# Ordering records by foreign field while maintaining adding capability

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have an Access form that lists all records in a table. One column in that table refers to a 'device' table, which then has a foreign key reference to a 'brand' column. In the form, the brand name + device name are displayed due to some magic in a combo box for every row.

The question: how can I sort this form by the brand name, while still retaining the ability to create new records? This is my current query:

```
SELECT ehs.*
FROM ehs, brand, device
WHERE brand.ID=device.brand_id AND ehs.device_id=device.ID
ORDER BY brand.brand_name, device.model;
```

Apparently (and understandably), you cannot add records when the query has a join in it. What would be a better approach to sorting the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can** create a form that has a foreign key in the query that allows adds and updates.  I've just done this in Access 2010 to confirm.

It's possible that some of the magic you mentioned with the combo boxes has broken the ability to do so.

**Note:** I've just noticed I've used `DeviceName` where you've used `model` - you'll need to adjust the SQL below.

There are some tricks, though:

- Make sure all of your tables have primary keys (hard to avoid in Access)
- Make sure all your foreign keys are indexed (so brand_id in device table, and device_id in ehs table) - duplicates ok.
- Use the relationships diagram to draw the relationships between these tables

I then created a query  - I just used the query designer, so Access' interesting brackety arrangement is all its own doing:

```
SELECT ehs.*
FROM (Brand INNER JOIN Device ON Brand.brandID = Device.BrandID) INNER JOIN ehs ON Device.DeviceID = ehs.DeviceID
ORDER BY Brand.Brandname, Device.DeviceName;
```

If you view that in a data sheet view you should be able to add a record.  That's important, if you can't there's a problem, if you can then we're on the way.

If this works, then I'd suggest create a **new** form based on this query and verify that the new form allows you to add records.  This new form is basically going to have an id number for device_id.  So you'll have to type a number to make it work.

The trick you're going to want to perform is, and I'm guessing the thing that's causing you problems:

> To have a "brand" drop-down that you choose a brand, which then limits the options for the device drop-down.

That's REAL tricky (and I'm afraid I'm somewhat rusty in Access, and it's not in the question, really).

What you **CAN** do, easily, instead, is have a drop-down for device, that includes the brand name, and sort that appropriately.

I added a combo box to the form.  The wizard takes you through using a table or query, I just chose the device table (we'll tweak this later), and the fields - you need device_id model and brand_id, and what to display (model and brand_id - we'll tweak it) and it hides the primary key.  When it says "do you want to save it for later or store it in this field, choose store it in this field and choose device_id (which is in the ehs table).

When the wizard completes, click on the new combo box, and get the properties for it. Switch to the Data tab, an there's a builder [...] button next to `RowSource`.  Click that, you get a query builder. Add the Brand table and show the brand_name field and hide the brand-id field.  (We just chose that so the combo box has two columns).  Sort as you like.

When you close it, it will ask you if you want to save it, so say yes.  Your SQL will be something like (with appropriate field name changes because of my mistake):

```
SELECT Device.DeviceID, Brand.Brandname, Device.DeviceName
FROM Brand INNER JOIN Device ON Brand.brandID = Device.BrandID
ORDER BY Device.DeviceName;
```

Your form should now have a combo box that shows the device name when not selected, and device name and brand name when you select the drop-down.

You can then delete the original device_id text box from the form.

And you can also add the brand name to the source query and add it as a text field on your form, so you can see the brand next to the device, even when it's not in the drop-down.

The primary query for the form can be:

```
SELECT ehs.*, Brand.Brandname
FROM (Brand INNER JOIN Device ON Brand.brandID = Device.BrandID) INNER JOIN ehs ON Device.DeviceID = ehs.DeviceID
ORDER BY Brand.Brandname, Device.DeviceName;
```

You can add BrandName as a text box - you don't need devicename (model) because this shows in the combo box.

And you should still be able to add records.

So, not ideal, but a lot simpler than coding up a bunch of VBA, which is where I think you'd need to go if you wanted to separate your combo boxes (not sure), especially as that's not the original question anyway.

I suggest you do each step and verify that it's still working at each stage.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks a lot! I adjusted the first query you gave and set it as the record source, and it works now. Guess Access doesn't quite understand the `WHERE table1, table2`-syntax...